# highcharts options clickable category name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, highcharts

I am using [HighCharts](http://highcharts.com), javascript plugin for making charts.
What I want is to find the option handling the click event on **Category** name and get its properties as shown in this picture:

## HighCharts

[image: highcharts clickable category]

I know HighCharts uses JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the event handler to the `first` `highcharts-axis`. Which's `categories` container.

So, **for categories**:

```
$('#container .highcharts-axis:first tspan').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/WqZcP/)

Comment: For the latest version of Highcharts, use `$("#container .highcharts-axis-labels:first text")` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the click event on the svg element. Working example here: http://livecoding.io/3492608. The gist of it:

```
$('.highcharts-axis text').click(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: thanks, but as you can see, all of texts are clickable now. so numbers and vertical text. I just want the **categories** to be clickable.

Comment: I see. Hmm, interesting problem. There isn't a native way to handle this in Highcharts. You could always hack the source code. I'll try to post an example of how to do that.